# Symfony @ParamConverter get entity through user relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have several routes that start with `/experiment/{id}/...` and I'm tired of rewriting the same logic to retrieve the signed in user's experiment. I guess I could refactor my code but I'm guessing `@ParamConverter` would be a better solution.

How would I rewrite the following code to take advantage of Symfony's [@ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) functionality?

```
/**
 * Displays details about an Experiment entity, including stats.
 *
 * @Route("/experiment/{id}/report", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="experiment_report")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function reportAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $experiment = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Experiment')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'id'   => $id,
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
        ));

    if (!$experiment) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Experiment entity.');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Experiment entities have [composite primary keys](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html) as follows:

```
class Experiment
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="experiments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    // ..

}
```

I want to retrieve a signed in user's experiment using their user `id` and an experiment `id` in the route.

Comment: Custom param converter will be enough, just inject `security.token_storage` and `doctrine` as arguments into your custom param converter service. http://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/symfony2-custom-paramconverter

Comment: Many thanks @malcolm I've accepted jkucharovic's answer, which details exactly what you suggest :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [custom `ParamConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter). For example something like that:

```
namespace AppBundle\Request\ParamConverter;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use AppBundle\Entity\Experiment;

class ExperimentConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    protected $em;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $object = $this->em->getRepository(Experiment::class)->findOneBy([
            'id'   => $request->attributes->get('id'),
            'user' => $this->user
        ]);

        if (null === $object) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(
                sprintf('%s object not found.', $configuration->getClass())
            );
        }

        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $object);

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return Experiment::class === $configuration->getClass();
    }
}
```

You need to register your converter service and add a tag to it:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    experiment_converter:
        class: AppBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ExperimentConverter
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
            - "@security.token_storage"
        tags:
            - { name: request.param_converter, priority: 1, converter: experiment_converter }
```

Comment: Many thanks @jkucharovic this works great :)  I had to change the `supports()` method slightly to make sure the class name is always in the correct format. I've updated your answer to reflect my change

Comment: For anyone that runs across this in the future, this works perfectly.  If you forget to set the resulting object into the request attributes (right before return true) you get an error where symfony thinks you've forgotten to register a new service.  I extended this example into a more generic converter so that I can use one Converter to Rule Them All.

Comment: @jkucharovic How would this work for multiple entities when you are hard coding a single entity in the converter class? And could you give an example of the ParamConverter annotation that would be applied to the controller method that wants to use this please?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't inject the currently logged in users id into the param converter, unless you actually pass it as a parameter in the url.

You could create your own converter, but I think your best bet would be to just create a protected method for fetching the experiment. It will be just as easy to use and maintain as an annotation:

```
protected function getCurrentUsersExperiment($experimentId)
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Experiment')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'id' => $experimentId,
            'user' => $this->getUser()
        ));
}

public function reportAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $experiment = $this->getCurrentUsersExperiment($id);

    ...
}
```

As it's noted in the [symfony best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html): use `ParamFetcher` whenever appropriate, but don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

While the question already has an answer, I'd like to add my two cents to it:

It looks like you may be solving a wrong problem: is your objective to prevent access to other user's experiments? If so, just load the Experiment object, and use a [Security Voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) to determine whether the current user can access the experiment or not.

Using the param converter the way you want will throw a 404 error instead of 401, with the same ultimate result: access to other people's experiments is denied. Unless you're trying to conceal the existence of a particular experiment ID, you might as well return a HTTP response reflecting the actual situation - 401, not 404. I would argue that obscuring the existence of some ID has probably no real benefit.

If nothing else, then using the security voter to deny access sounds like more fit-for-purpose and reusable approach in Symfony context, comparing to a homebrew param converter.

If you don't want to use a security voter, you could also get away with [using an expression](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#2-fetch-via-an-expression): if your Experiment's repository class was autowiring the Security object, you would be able to fetch the current user from the repository class. If that repository class has a method `findCurrentUserExperiment(int $id)`, the usage would be close to:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/experiment/{experiment}/report", requirements={"experiment" = "\d+"}, name="experiment_report")
 * @Entity("experiment", expr="repository.findCurrentUserExperiment(experiment)")
 */
public function reportAction(Request $request, ?Experiment $experiment)
```

I still think that a security voter is a better fit, but at least with the expression you wouldn't have to manage a narrow-use-case ParamConverter.